# Авторизация и хранение сессии в Android

Tags: android, сессия, авторизация

Никак не могу понять как в Android приложении

- хранить сессию пользователя ?
- как генерировать токен и где его хранить ?
- как привязывать его к id юзера
- что передавать между Activity для запоминания пользователя?
- Какие средства для этого есть в Android разработке?
- Приемлемо ли будет для этого использовать сервлеты?
- Может кто изложить алгоритм как это все происходит?